# Flutter: when parent uses setState(), children's state reset

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-state

I'm developing an Android app to learn to use flutter/dart. It's a download time calculator and simulator where I have a listView of downloadSimulator.

this is the code of main.dart:

```
import 'utils/ad_helper.dart';
import 'widgets/speed_test.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'widgets/control_panel.dart';
import 'widgets/download_simulator.dart'; // Importa il file control_panel.dart

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  MobileAds.instance.initialize();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Download time calculator',
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: false,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late BannerAd _bottomBannerAd;
  bool _isBottomBannerAdLoaded = false;
  final TextEditingController _fileSizeController = TextEditingController();
  String _selectedDropdownSizeUnit = "MB";
  final List<DownloadSimulator> _downloadSimulators = [];
  String wantedState = "waiting";

  void _createBottomBannerAd() {
    _bottomBannerAd = BannerAd(
        size: AdSize.banner,
        adUnitId: AdHelper.bannerAdUnitId,
        listener: BannerAdListener(onAdLoaded: (_) {
          setState(() {
            _isBottomBannerAdLoaded = true;
          });
        }, onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {
          ad.dispose();
          print('Failed to load a banner ad: ${error.message}');
        }),
        request: const AdRequest());

    _bottomBannerAd.load();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _downloadSimulators.add(DownloadSimulator(
      fileSize: double.tryParse(_fileSizeController.text) ?? 0,
      selectedDropdownSizeUnit: _selectedDropdownSizeUnit,
      wantedState: wantedState,
    ));
    _createBottomBannerAd();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _bottomBannerAd.dispose();
  }

  void _addSimulator() {
    setState(() {
      _downloadSimulators.add(DownloadSimulator(
        fileSize: double.tryParse(_fileSizeController.text) ?? 0,
        selectedDropdownSizeUnit: _selectedDropdownSizeUnit,
        wantedState: wantedState,
      ));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: _isBottomBannerAdLoaded
          ? SizedBox(
              height: _bottomBannerAd.size.height.toDouble(),
              width: _bottomBannerAd.size.width.toDouble(),
              child: AdWidget(ad: _bottomBannerAd),
            )
          : null,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        foregroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: const Text("Download time calculator"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const SpeedTest(),
                ),
              );
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.speed),
            tooltip: "Go to speedtest",
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ControlPanel(
            // Utilizza il widget ControlPanel
            fileSizeController: _fileSizeController,
            selectedDropdownSizeUnit: _selectedDropdownSizeUnit,
            changeFileSizeUnit: (String fileSizeUnit) => setState(
              () => _selectedDropdownSizeUnit = fileSizeUnit,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              if (_downloadSimulators.isEmpty) {
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  const SnackBar(
                    duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                    content: Text("First add a download simulator"),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                setState(() {
                  wantedState = "ready";
                });
              }
            },
          ),
          _downloadSimulators.isEmpty
              ? const Expanded(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "Add a download simulator",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: _downloadSimulators.length,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Dismissible(
                        key: UniqueKey(),
                        onDismissed: (_) => setState(
                          () => _downloadSimulators.removeAt(index),
                        ),
                        background: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                        child: _downloadSimulators[index],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: SizedBox(
        width: 30,
        height: 30,
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _addSimulator,
          tooltip: 'Add simulator',
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code of download_simulator.dart:

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:speed_test_dart/enums/file_size.dart';
import '../utils/utils.dart';

enum DownloadSimulatorState { waiting, ready, simulating }

class DownloadSimulator extends StatefulWidget {
  final double fileSize;
  final String selectedDropdownSizeUnit;
  final String wantedState;

  const DownloadSimulator({
    super.key,
    required this.fileSize,
    required this.selectedDropdownSizeUnit,
    required this.wantedState,
  });

  @override
  State<DownloadSimulator> createState() => _DownloadSimulatorState();
}

class _DownloadSimulatorState extends State<DownloadSimulator> {
  TextEditingController _bandwithController = TextEditingController();
  String _selectedDropdownSpeedUnit = "Mbps";
  double _timeToTransfer = -1;
  double _speed = -1;
  double _transfered = -1;
  double _percentage = -1;
  DownloadSimulatorState _state = DownloadSimulatorState.waiting;

  void reset() {
    setState(() {
      //TODO: reset all the values and set state to waiting
    });
  }

  void calculate() {
    setState(() {
      double bytesToTransfer = convertToB(
        widget.fileSize,
        _selectedDropdownSpeedUnit,
      );
      double transferSpeed = convertToBps(
        double.parse(_bandwithController.text),
        _selectedDropdownSpeedUnit,
      );
      _timeToTransfer = calculateMillisecondsToTransfer(
        bytesToTransfer,
        transferSpeed,
      );
      _speed = transferSpeed;
      _state = DownloadSimulatorState.ready;
    });
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant DownloadSimulator oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);

    if (widget.wantedState != oldWidget.wantedState) {
      if (widget.wantedState == "ready") {
        calculate(); // Chiama calculate() quando isCalculating diventa true.
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: 75,
                height: 35,
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Bandwith",
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                  controller: _bandwithController,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                      RegExp(
                        r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}',
                      ),
                    ),
                    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(8),
                  ], // Only numbers can be entered
                  keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                    decimal: true,
                    signed: false,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Text("percentage"),
              Visibility(
                  visible: _state != DownloadSimulatorState.waiting,
                  child: Text(formatTimeToTransfer(_timeToTransfer))),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          LinearProgressIndicator(
            value: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                  width: 75,
                  child: Visibility(
                      visible: _state != DownloadSimulatorState.waiting,
                      child: Text(formatTransferSpeed(_speed)))),
              FittedBox(
                child: DropdownButton(
                  items: const [
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: "Kbps",
                      child: Text('Kbps'),
                    ),
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: "Mbps",
                      child: Text('Mbps'),
                    ),
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: "Gbps",
                      child: Text('Gbps'),
                    ),
                  ],
                  onChanged: (value) => setState(
                    () => _selectedDropdownSpeedUnit = value ?? "Mbps",
                  ),
                  value: _selectedDropdownSpeedUnit,
                  underline: Container(
                    height: 0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Text("transfered"),
            ],
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code of control_panel.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class ControlPanel extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController fileSizeController;
  final String selectedDropdownSizeUnit;
  final Function changeFileSizeUnit;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  ControlPanel({
    super.key,
    required this.fileSizeController,
    required this.selectedDropdownSizeUnit,
    required this.changeFileSizeUnit,
    required this.onPressed,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: 100,
              child: TextField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "File size",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                controller: fileSizeController,
                inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                    RegExp(
                      r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}',
                    ),
                  ),
                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(8),
                ], // Only numbers can be entered
                keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                  decimal: true,
                  signed: false,
                ),
                //onChanged: (value) => amountInput = value,
              ),
            ),
            FittedBox(
              child: DropdownButton(
                items: const [
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: "KB",
                    child: Text('KB'),
                  ),
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: "MB",
                    child: Text('MB'),
                  ),
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: "GB",
                    child: Text('GB'),
                  ),
                ],
                onChanged: (selectedFileSizeUnit) =>
                    changeFileSizeUnit(selectedFileSizeUnit),
                value: selectedDropdownSizeUnit,
                underline: Container(
                  height: 0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton.icon(
              onPressed: onPressed,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.calculate),
              label: const Text('Calculate'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Look of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYh5A.png)
The problem is that when in main.dart a setState is called, all the download_simulators get rebuild and their state is lost. I don't want it. Instead I need them to keep their state. What is wrong? For example if I change Mbps to let's say Kbps and then I click on calculate, it changes back to Mbps because the state get a reset. Please help me, I'm a noob with flutter and dart.

I expect that the state are separated but I need download simulators to access to filesize, selectedDropdownSizeUnit, wantedState that are in main.dart

Comment: Part of rebuilding is asking your kids to rebuild as well.

Comment: Why? And what can I do to prevent children from rebuilding?

Comment: You should not care if your child rebuilds 60 or 120 times per second.  build() should be fast and have no sideeffects.

Comment: The problem is that when main rebuild, also my children get rebuilt and they lost their state (they reset)

Comment: You need to put state in something that persists between build().  This is fundamental to coding for widgets.